# InflateException Binary XML file at line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I've been doing some research of this problem but no solution has yet to work for me. I've added empty constructors in the fragment classes and tried with different imports of fragments, but nothing seems to work. I hope you guys can help me!

**My Activity:**

```
package com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RssfeedActivity extends Activity implements MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssfeed);
}

public void onRssItemSelected(String link) {
    DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);

    if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
        fragment.setText(link);
    }//end if
}//end method onRssItemSelected

}//end class
```

**My fragment:**

```
package com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

public MyListFragment() {

}

private OnItemSelectedListener listener;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDetail();
        }//end onClick
    });
    return view;
}//end onCreateView

public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onRssItemSelected(String link);
}//end onItemSelectedListener

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

        if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
            listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;

        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + "Must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }//end else

}//end onAttach

//May also be triggered from the activity
public void updateDetail() {
    //Create fake data
    String newTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Send data to Activity
    listener.onRssItemSelected(newTime);
}//end method updateDetail
}//end class
```

**My fragment XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"></fragment>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.rssfeed.DetailFragment"></fragment>




</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed.RssfeedActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Button XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Press to Update">

</button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat error:**

```
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed/com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed.RssfeedActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed.RssfeedActivity.onCreate(RssfeedActivity.java:11)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     ... 11 more
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4862)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     ... 21 more
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed-1.apk
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
05-17 10:35:01.864: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed-1.apk

Change this

```
 class="com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment"
```

to

```
 class="com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment"
```

cause the packagename is `package com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed`.

Similarly

```
 class="com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed.DetailFragment"
```

if the package name is the same

Change this

```
<button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Press to Update">
```

To

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Press to Update" />
```

Comment: Ah thx for pointing that out, passed right over my head lol. Now its giving me: Error inflating class button, instead. Do I need to add a class package to it also?

Comment: @user3572555 no you don't

Comment: ah okay, I added the xml for the button to the paste.

Comment: @user3572555 its `<Button` not `<button`. Edited

Comment: Ah! Such silly noob misstakes, I think I need my coffee now. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"class= com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment"
```

to

```
"com.example.com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment"


 And your problem will be solved out
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in fragment 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"